# Convert html string to image or canvas in React js

Tags: reactjs

I have an array of objects where one of the properties is an html string.
When rendering each object, I want to **render this html but in image or canvas** format to be able to control width and height.

I want to do it **without rendering the html**, is it possible? Is there any other alternative?